# Magento2 - Single product page image URLs lead to "small_image" folder

Tags: image, magento2

I'm losing some quality and sharpness in my catalog images when I upload them to Magento. On the single product pages, the enlarged gallery images lead to URLs with "small_image" in the file path, like the following:

https://www.opulentjewelers.com/media/catalog/product/c/a/cartier-panthere-onyx-diamond-earrings-1.jpg

Shouldn't these large images be in the "image" folder? Is there any way for me to ensure that my single product pages are using the largest, uncompressed image available?

Thanks for your help.